# How to solve for P in a similarity when matrices aren't diagonalizable

Tags: linear-algebra

When matrices $A,B$ are similar and they are both diagonalizable, as
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
P_1^{-1}AP_1=Λ\\
P_2^{-1}BP_2=Λ
\end{array}
\right.
\Longrightarrow (P_1P_2^{-1})^{-1}A(P_1P_2^{-1})=B$$

then we know when $P=P_1P_2^{-1}$, we can get $P^{-1}AP=B$.  We just solve for the eigenvectors of $A$ and $B$, and then we can easily get the $P_1$ and $P_2$.

---

My question is about how to proceed when $A$ and $B$ are similar yet not both diagonalizable. How can we solve for a matrix $P$ so that $B = P^{-1}A P$?

I have two example in following:

## First

$A=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 \\
\end{array} 
\right)$ and $B=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 -\frac{12}{7} & -\frac{32}{7} \\
 \frac{9}{14} & \frac{12}{7} \\
\end{array}
\right)$.  How to get the $P$?
<sub>Actually I know the $P= ( \begin{smallmatrix} 2&10\\3&8 \end{smallmatrix} ) $</sub>

## Second

$A=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 27 & 48 & 81 \\
 -6 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 3 \\
\end{array}
\right)$ and $
B=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 52 & 62 & 24 \\
 4 & 8 & 0 \\
 -80 & -\frac{197}{2} & -30 \\
\end{array}
\right)$
.How to solve the $P$?<sub>Actually the $P=\left(
\begin{smallmatrix}
 8 & 10 & 0 \\
 5 & 3 & 4 \\
 0 & 2 & 0 \\
\end{smallmatrix}
\right)$</sub>

Comment: In your example, $A, B$ are not similar.

Comment: Let me try to restate your Question in my words.  Suppose $A,B$ are similar but not diagonalizable.  How can we compute a matrix $P$ which accomplishes the similarity transformation $B = P^{-1}A P$?

Comment: @xpaul Oh,I can sure they are similar.you can calculate $P^{-1}AP$,it equal to $B$ exactly.

Comment: @xpaul:  Notice the denominator in the lower left corner is $14$, which cancels a factor of two in the upper right corner.  So the trace and determinant are zero for both matrices.  I think they must be similar.

Comment: @hardmath Yes,you get my meaning.Thanks.

Comment: Two matrices are similar if and only if they have the same Jordan canonical form (or rational canonical form if you don't wish to pass to a field extension). You can use the exact same procedure you did with the diagonalizable case, with $\Lambda$ replaced with $J$, the Jordan canonical form.

Comment: @EuYu I get your meaning.And I made it by **Mathematica**.Thanks a lot.Do you think I should post  a answer with **Mathematica code**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets take this the other way

First of all we find one eigenvector the same way we normally would

$B\mathbf v_1 = \lambda \mathbf v_1$

In this case $\lambda = 0$ and $\mathbf v_1 = \begin{bmatrix}8\\-3\end{bmatrix}$

we have one vector in P, we need to find the other such that.

$BP = P\Lambda + P\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}\\
(B-\lambda I) P = P\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}\\
(B-\lambda I) \mathbf v_2 = \mathbf v_1$

Since $\lambda$ equals $0,$ you have made life easier on us... but not that much easier..

$B \mathbf v_2 = \mathbf v_1\\
B^2 \mathbf v_2 = B\mathbf v_1 = 0\\$

But $B^2 = 0$ which gives us a lot of latitude to find suitable $\mathbf v_2$
There is not a unique solution.  Any solution will suffice.

$-\frac {12}7  v_{2,1} -\frac{32}{7} v_{2,2} = 8\\
3 v_{2,1} + 8 v_{2,2} = -14\\
3\cdot6 + 8 \cdot -4 = -14$

$P = \begin{bmatrix}8& 6\\-3&-4\end{bmatrix}$

$BP = PA$ or $P^{-1} B P = A$

Update....

If you can't diagonalize the matrix, can you put it into "Jordan Normal" form?

$P^{-1}A P
=  \begin{bmatrix}
 \lambda_1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & \lambda_2 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & \lambda_2 \\
\end{bmatrix}$

If you can put two matrices into the same Jordan Normal form, they are similar.

$A = \begin{bmatrix}
 27 & 48 & 81 \\
 -6 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 3 \\
\end{bmatrix}$

The characteristic equation is: $(\lambda - 6)(\lambda-12)^2 = 0$

We find the first two eigenvectors using the normal approach.

$A \begin{bmatrix} 3\\-3\\1\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 18\\-18\\6\end{bmatrix}$

$A \begin{bmatrix} 18\\-9\\2\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 216\\-108\\24\end{bmatrix}$

the $3^{rd}$ eigenvector....

$(A -12 I)^2 = \begin{bmatrix} 18&144&486\\-18&-144&-486\\6&48&162\end{bmatrix}$

Any vector in the kernel of the above is parallel to the second eigenvector.  Now you just need to scale it!

$\begin{bmatrix} 3\\3\\-1\end{bmatrix}$ is in the kernel.

$A \begin{bmatrix} 3\\3\\-1\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}108\\-54\\12\end{bmatrix}= 6 \begin{bmatrix} 18\\-9\\2\end{bmatrix}$

$P = \begin{bmatrix} 3&18&\frac 12\\-3&9&\frac 12\\1&2&\frac 16\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: Thank for your solution,I get a lot from it.But maybe the first $A$ have some special.Can you make this solution more universal?Then I'll accept it and this post can help other people which have same confusion with me also.I'm look forward that.

Comment: I added some more information.  Does this help?

Comment: Wow,I'm thinks for your heavy work for me.Actually I'm currently solve the p by this method by **Mathematica**.But this is module of **Mathematics**.So I have not post my solution as answer.Anyway,thinks very very much. :)